# Find angle of an arc in the circle using 3 coordinates

Tags: circles, triangles

I want to find angle of semicircle. I have 3 coordinates (center_a,center_b) , (pivot_a,pivot_b) and (last_point_a, last_point_b).

From triangle , i can find angle using equation
 [image: find angle from cosine inverse]

using cosine inverse ,we get angle.   But on circle, angle can be 0 to 360.   Can anyone help me to find angle of arc?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking. Do the pivot and the last point lie on the arc of the semicircle? Which angle are you trying to find?

Comment: Pivot and last point are the two end points in the arc

Comment: @oliveeuler Sorry, the term semi circle was mistakenly added

Comment: You've shown that you can find the angle subtended by an arc of a circle; you have to know which quadrant it's in (i.e. if the angle is $0<\theta<90^\circ$ or $90<\theta<180^\circ$ etc.) this will tell you the total angle. Consider drawing the figure to see if the angle you've found makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @oliveeuler    add 180 if necessary after checking quadrant of points.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more explicit.